# Const_missing hook isn't fired

Tags: ruby, constants

I money patched `const_missing` methods into `Object` and in difference contexts:

auto_loader.rb

```
%w{../../lib ../../app}.each do |path|
  expanded_path = File.expand_path(path,__FILE__)
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift(expanded_path) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(expanded_path)
end
class Object
def self.inherited(base)
    base.extend(Class_Methods)
    super
  end

  def const_missing(const)
    puts "loading(in Object) %s" % const.to_s
    path = const.to_s.split('::').compact.map(&:downcase).join('/') 
    require path
    self.const_get(const)
  end
  class << self
    def const_missing(const)
      puts "loading(in Object class << self) %s" % const.to_s
      path = const.to_s.split('::').compact.map(&:downcase).join('/') 
      require path
      self.const_get(const)
    end
  end
  module Class_Methods
    class << self
      def const_missing(const)
        puts "loading(in Class_Methods class << self) %s" % const.to_s
        path = const.to_s.split('::').compact.map(&:downcase).join('/') 
        require path
        self.const_get(const)
      end
    end



    def const_missing(const)
      puts "loading(in Class_Methods) %s" % const.to_s
      path = const.to_s.split('::').compact.map(&:downcase).join('/') 
      require path
      self.const_get(const)
    end

  end

  extend Class_Methods
end
```

When I run the code, I see:

```
NameError: Uninitialized constant CONST
```

without any of the `puts` displayed.

I also load the code with:

```
pry -r ./lib/auto_loader.rb
```

The result is the same.

On the other hand, if I manually fire the `const_missing` method, I see `loading(in Object) const`.

Why is `const_missing` hook not fired?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not minimal and does not run. If I try the following it works without any problem. I think your problem is related to something else.

```
class Object

  def self.inherited(base)
    base.extend(Class_Methods)
    super
  end

  def self.const_missing_impl(const, location)
    puts "loading(in #{location}) %s" % const.to_s
    path = const.to_s.split('::').compact.map(&:downcase).join('/') 
    puts "require #{path}"
  end

  def const_missing(const)
    Object.const_missing_impl(const, 'Object')
  end

  class << self
    def const_missing(const)
      Object.const_missing_impl(const, 'Object class << self')
    end
  end

  module Class_Methods
    def const_missing(const)
      Object.const_missing_impl(const, 'Class_Methods')
    end

    class << self
      def const_missing(const)
        Object.const_missing_impl(const, 'Class_Methods class << self')
      end
    end
  end

  extend Class_Methods
end

a = CONST1
b = a::CONST2
c = String::CONST3
d = Class_Methods::CONST4

# Prints
loading(in Object class << self) CONST1
require const1
loading(in Object class << self) CONST2
require const2
loading(in Object class << self) CONST3
require const3
loading(in Class_Methods class << self) CONST4
require const4
```